# How to set the session timeout for the embeded Jetty server when using Spark Java microframework?

Tags: java, servlets

Basically what the title says. I know how to set it using web.xml but I cannot find a way to set the session timeout when using jetty as embedded server in [Spark Java](http://sparkjava.com/).
I am looking for a global setting, not the `request.session().maxInactiveInterval(int)` which sets it per session.